# Using a class' "index"?

Tags: c#

How do I write the code to add two vectors a , b using the X,Y and Z co-ordinates.
The below code shows where I'm struck exactly.

```
        public Vector(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        float X, Y, Z;
        X = _x;
        Y = _y;
        Z = _z;
        Vector _vector = new Vector(X, Y, Z);
    }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector _a, Vector _b)
    {
        return new Vector();    //_a.X + _b.X , _a.Y + _b.Y, _a.Z + _b.Z
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post screen shots, better paste your code here.

Comment: Copy-pasted code will explain your problem more than a photo could

Comment: You will have StackOverflow exception with this code - you are creating new vector while you are creating new vector while you are creation new vector while..

Comment: This code does not make sense yet. 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' should probably be _members_ instead of local variables in your constructor. Plus your constructor creates a `StackOverflowException` as it is constantly calling itself.

Comment: I dont know how to write return new Vector(........); , because the syntax is unclear

Comment: Please improve your question by using a more descriptive title, showing example code in Markdown and showing desired outcome.

Comment: Why are you creating a new Vector inside your Vector constructor? As @SergeyBerezovskiy said, this will create an infinite recursion of new vectors. Also, why are you assigning your constructor parameters to local variables instead of just using the constructor parameters? Are you trying to assign the constructor parameters to class _members_?

Comment: “My code will explain my problem more than I could.” — Actually … your code explains nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Create properties from your incoming parameters. Then you can use them anywhere in your class:

```
public class Vector
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }

    public Vector(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        X = _x;
        Y = _y;
        Z = _z;
    }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector _a, Vector _b)
    {
        return new Vector(_a.X + _b.X, _a.Y + _b.Y, _a.Z + _b.Z);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is in a struct, not in a class, sadly

Comment: Your title says it is a class... But still the code works for structs too.

Answer (score 2):

```
public struct Vector
{
    public float X { get; }
    public float Y { get; }
    public float Z { get; }

    public Vector(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.X + b.X , a.Y + b.Y, a.Z + b.Z);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Seems like you don't understand difference between local variables and class fields/properties. When you declare variables inside method or constructor - those variables and their values will be gone after method call. When you declare variables in the class/struct body, those values will be available during object lifetime.
- Seems like you don't understand purpose of constructor. It's not for creating new instance of type - it's for initializing instance which is already created. Your current code will fail with StackOverflow exception, because constructor is called to initialize values of new Vector instance. If you create new Vector instance in constructor, then constructor will be called to initialize that new instance. And so on until exception.
- Don't use weird underscores in variable or parameter names.